# mysql get list of all products ordered per customer in date range open cart

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get a list of customers and what they ordered out of the database to send out weekly statements i want results to display like:

customer firstname customer lastname

order_product name  order_product quantity 
order_product name  order_product quantity 
etc..

for each customer

Here are my tables (left irrelevant columns out its default open cart if that helps):

**Customer**

firstname
lastname

**order**

customer_id 
order_id 
date_added

**order_products**

order_id
name
quantity

got working thanks to Catcall - date range

```
    $sql =  "select c.customer_id, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
                       o.order_id, o.date_added, 
                       op.name, op.quantity
                from `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c
                inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
                inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op on o.order_id = op.order_id";
```

could someone please explain how to process array to the format previously requested php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, you'd do something along these lines to get the data.

```
select c.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, 
       o.order_id, o.date_added, 
       op.name, op.quantity
from customer c
inner join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join order_products op on o.order_id = op.order_id
where date_added > current_date - interval '7' day;
```

But date arithmetic is highly platform-dependent.

You normally wouldn't be concerned with how things lined up at the SQL level. Putting the customer's name on the first line of output, and putting product names on the second line is a display issue--your report writer should be responsible for that. (Among other things, that lets you use the same query for a lot of different reports.)

Comment: I'm getting 'Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id inner join order_products op on o.' at line 5
Error No: 1064
select c.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, o.order_id, o.date_added, op.name, op.quantity from customer c inner join order o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id inner join order_products op on o.order_id = op.order_id in /Users/iMac/Sites/responsivecart/system/database/mysql.php on line 49'

Comment: On MySQL, you should probably [enclose identifiers in backticks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html). (*order* is a reserved word.)

Comment: [MySQL date arithmetic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)